# post form with jquery validate

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, post

I'm desperately trying to send a form with the POST method and the [jquery validate plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/).

I have a simple php file which is supposed to send an email with the data form.

Being a Mac user, I'm using [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) to test the php server part.

I looked at the web console when i click on my form's submit button and the status is ok:

```
[15:32:50,638] POST http://localhost:8888/contact.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 36ms]
```

But nothing happens. It looks my contact.php file is never reached!

I tried uploading my files to the server, I have the same result: nothing.

Here is my form, in html:

```
<form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="" action="">
<fieldset class="myfield">
<legend>For all information, please contact us with the following form :</legend>
<p>
<label class="mylabel" for="iname"><span style="color:red;">* </span>Nom</label>
<input class="myinput" id="iname" name="iname" minlength="2" maxlength="50" type="text" required/>
</p>
<p>
<label class="mylabel" for="imail"><span style="color:red;">* </span>Email</label>
<input class="myinput" id="imail" name="imail" minlength="3" maxlength="100" type="email" required email/>
</p>
<p>
<label class="mylabel" for="isubject"><span style="color:red;">* </span>Sujet</label>
<input class="myinput" id="isubject" name="isubject" minlength="3" maxlength="130" type="text" required/>
</p>
<label class="mylabel" for="imessage" style="vertical-align: top;"><span style="color:red;">* </span> Message</label>
<textarea class="mytextarea" id="imessage" name="imessage" minlength="3" maxlength="2000" type="text" required></textarea>
</p>
<p>
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Send"/>
</p>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

and for the jquery part, I'm using the [post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) method:

```
$('#commentForm').validate({

 errorClass : "myerror",
 errorElement : 'em',
 submitHandler: function() {       
       $.post( 'contact.php', { name : 'john' } ); //just for testing, i would normally pass the form data
        }
  });
```

and the php part, well it's a simple email forwarding:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$message = <<<TEXT
name: {$_POST['name']}
email: {$_POST['email']}
subject: {$_POST['subject']}
message: {$_POST['message']}    
TEXT;

$header ='From: contact@xxxxxx.com'."\n";
$header .='Reply-To: '.$_POST['name']."\n";
$header .='Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"'."\n"; 
$header .='Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit';

$to = 'yyyyyy@contact.com';

$subject = $_POST['subject'];

if( ! mail($to, $subject, $message, $header) ) 
{ 
   die('Error sending email.');
}else {
  die(    'Email sent!'.$to .
        'sub:' .$subject .
        'message:' .$message .
        'header:' .$header);
}
```

What am i doing wrong? Being new to the html development, I'm puzzled. I've already browsed SO to find similar issues, and tried to copy/paste example but I still have my problem.

Thanks for any help..

Answer (score 0):

the name of input in your html file is different from php file

```
 <input class="myinput" id="iname" name="iname" minlength="2" maxlength="50" type="text" required/>
```

here the name is `"iname"`

in php file

```
name: {$_POST['name']}
```

name is `name`

correct this and see the result

Comment: it doesn't work either :( actually, i can transmit anything in the jquery post() function, it won't change anything to it. I have tried a to edit the contact.php and add a simple 'phpinfo()' and that php file does't seem to be reached.

Comment: maybe you should check you php configure